When I deploy a Google Cloud Function in Typescript, it also deploys my .ts files
I have my file structure like this:
tsconfig.json
package.json
src/ts files..
lib/js files..

When I deploy the function using firebase deploy, I notice that it also uploads the .ts files. Is that the default behavior that is supposed to happen?
I know I can exclude them in the "ignore" setting of firebase.json, but I am wondering if there is some way to build the lib and just deploy only that folder.

Yes, this is supposed to happen.  The Firebase CLI will deploy the entire contents of the "functions" folder.  It's up to you to determine which, if any, files should be ignored from that, and arrange for that to happen.  The CLI has no good way of knowing if your doesn't actually need to read any given file at runtime after deployment, so it just deploys everything out of safety.
Realistically, leaving the .ts files in place will make no practical difference in a vast majority of cases.

Thanks for clarifying. Was just wondering if I had something misconfigured.
